# pandas list型にするには

Tags: python, pandas

csvファイル(A_csv)

```
  A B C D E F G H I J 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

をpandasを使いプログラム上に読み込み

```
リスト型
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

に変更したいのですが,

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1 2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10]
Index: []
```

となってしまいます.

```
a_data=pd.read_csv('A.csv')
```

を行った場合のprint(a_data)の出力は上のようになります.

Comment: 色々と前提条件とか途中の処理とかが省略されている感じで説明が不足しているようです。例えば最初にCSVファイルと書かれているのは既に読み込まれてDataFrameになったものを表示しているようですし、Empty DataFrame...と表示されるのは、どのような処理を行った結果なのかが書かれていません。そうしたことの詳細を追記してください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問に示されている`csvファイル(A_csv)`はExcel上での表示イメージでしょう。

CSVファイルとしては以下のようになるはずです。

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

ここで質問のようになってしまうのは、`read_csv()`のデフォルトでは1行目をヘッダー行として扱うからです。
`read_csv()`にパラメータとして`header=None`を加えれば上記ファイル内容がデータとして扱われるでしょう。

そしてそのデータ内容をリストとして取り出したい場合は`values.tolist()`を使います。
1行しかデータが無く、その行だけを1次元のリストとして取り出したい場合は、`values[0].tolist()`とすれば良いでしょう。

合わせると以下のようになるはずです。

```
import pandas as pd

a_data = pd.read_csv('A1.csv', header=None)
data = a_data.values[0].tolist()
print(data)
```

Comment: a_data = pd.read_csv('P1.csv', header=None)
data = a_data.values[0].tolist()
print(data) を行ったところ, ['1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10']と出力されるのですが.

Comment: それはCSVファイルがカンマ区切りではなく、@payaneco さん回答のようにタブ区切りになっているからでしょう。ファイル内容をカンマ区切りに変更するか、payanecoさん回答のように`read_csv()`に区切り文字を変更するパラメータを指定すれば良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。気づきませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

csvファイルの中身がご質問の通り下記の内容の場合、`pd.read_csv('A1.csv')`を実行すると…

```
  A B C D E F G H I J 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

`print(a_data)`の出力は下記になります。

```
     A B C D E F G H I J 
0  1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

csvファイルの中身を下記のようにタブやスペース区切りにしてヘッダを削除しないとお困りの状況に近づけられないのですが、内容に齟齬はないでしょうか。

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

もし上記のようにcsvファイルがヘッダ行のないタブ区切り形式で、1行目をリストにしたい場合は下記のコードで対応できます。

```
import pandas as pd

a_data=pd.read_csv('A1.csv', header=None, sep='\t') # ヘッダ行なし、タブ区切りを指定する
l = a_data.iloc[0].to_list()  # ilocで行番号を指定してSeriesを取得し、to_listでリスト化する
print(l)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

参考資料:
[pandasでcsv/tsvファイル読み込み（read_csv, read_table）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-read-csv-tsv/)
[pandas.DataFrameとSeriesを相互に変換](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-dataframe-series-conversion/)